# Lookup Value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, match, lookup

Good day everyone - I am trying to create a grade sheet for my swimming classes at school.  It needs to be based on a few criteria - 1. boys/girls, 2. What stroke, 3. Time swum

I have a column for Time swum and a column with a dropdown of boys freestyle, girls freestyle etc to choose from.  Then a criteria table where you get 30 point for swim x time less for each stroke for boys and girls.  I was trying to use index match - but that will only return one of the strokes.  As seen in the image - I need Column X to return the Points from column AB based on Column T dropdown selection, based on the range of the table with all the stroke times.

I've gotten this far : =index(AB2:AB6,MATCH(S2,AG2:AG6,1)), but that assumes all are swimming backstroke and all are girls.

I am hoping I am explaining this effectively enough.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Sample page]

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem?

Comment: @ashleedawg I think OP is trying to figure out how they can change their formula so they can programatically choose the column. Instead of just looking at the "Backstroke Girls" column, for example, they want to be able to change a text value on the sheet so it will look at a different column. Probably using the value from `T2` in their screenshot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it with `INDEX(MATCH(),MATCH())` but I'm having trouble getting my formula to work.

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg - I am trying to do a lookup for points based on time swum and stroke chosen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OFFSET` to move the column you are matchin to the right. Also my understanding is that is for example in column "Freestyle Girls" someone reaches time 50 she should be put into line 55 - Grade A, 25 Points. If so you will need to do this:

1) reverse order of your data lines - if you want to use MATCH with last parameter "-1" (returns lowest value greater or equal to lookup value) for time (when you reach 50, you are worse then 40 so you will go to line with 55) you will need to have the values in descending order so the grades will go D to A* instead of A* to D.

2) use formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AB:AB,MATCH(S2,OFFSET(AB:AB,0,MATCH(T2,AC1:AF1,0)),-1)),AB2)
```

Basically what it does is this:

```
OFFSET(AB:AB,0,MATCH(T2,AC1:AF1,0))
```

this moves the search column for the final `MATCH` to match the style you select

```
INDEX(AB:AB,MATCH(S2,OFFSET(...),-1))
```

this is standard search like you tried, only the `OFFSET` is inside so it looks in correct column.

As there is no value above Grade D it would cause error if somone nearly drowned and took 100 to finish so you need `IFERROR` to make sure it correct that.

**Note**: this assumes that value in T matches the values in the column names AC-AH. It your example the word order seems flipped. Also I put into my formula only 4 different styles so you will need to change the part stating `AC1:AF1` to contain all the styles

Comment: you are awesome! Thank you!  I have changed the name in the table to match the drop down!  And I actually did have it as "-1" - I think I was trying different things and didn't change it back.

Comment: quick question.  D I need to change the Offset to the whole table or just for the strokes in Row 1?  I keep getting 30 as my points doesn't matter what swim time or stroke I choose.

Comment: If you want to include more styles you only need to change AC1:AF1 to AC1:AH1 for example. Nothing else. If you keep getting 30 I would assume that the final INDEX is return error and you have the IFERROR pointed to 30. Try to remove the IFERROR to see if this is correct. If you have the OFFSET to whole table change that and also remeber to point the IFERROR to 10 points, not 30. If this doesnt work then probably the best thing to do would be to edit your answer and put there printscreen of how your data look.

Comment: Ok cool.  Let me try.  Also - should I change the time of Grade "D" to say 200 because then at least the really slow swimmer doesn't return an error?

Comment: depends on what you find better. You can either increase the time and remove the IFERROR or keep the IFERROR and point it to lowest point score. I guess increasing the time and removing the IFERROR would be more logical

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help! All sorted